# Ubuntu Focal, update systemd

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, sway

I can't run sway because of systemd v245 https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/15111

Except for a do-released-upgrade, how can I update systemd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with `sudo chmod a+s /use/bin/sway`, from: https://bugs.gentoo.org/708680#c19